# parse xml to json in php while having subnodes next to a textNode

Tags: php, xml, json, simplexml

I need to parse some xml from an external XML-API to JSON, to do so, I used this very [nice little library from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/!) which works very well so far. Unfortunately I discovered some text nodes have subnodes very next to some simple textnodes and aren't discovered as sub children:

simplified example:

```
<?php

$str = 
'<topics>
  <topic>Objekte mit Data Dictionary Views verwalten
    <sub_topics>
      <sub_topic>Data Dictionary erläutern</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Dictionary Views</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Views USER_OBJECTS und ALL_OBJECTS</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Tabellen- und Spalteninformationen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Dictionary Views nach Constraint-Informationen abfragen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Dictionary Views nach View-, Sequence-, Index- und Synonyminformationen abfragen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Tabellen Kommentare hinzufügen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Dictionary Views nach Kommentarinformationen abfragen</sub_topic>
    </sub_topics>
  </topic>
  <topic>Große Datensets bearbeiten
    <sub_topics>
      <sub_topic>Daten mithilfe von Unterabfragen bearbeiten</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Daten mit einer Unterabfrage als Quelle abrufen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>INSERT-Anweisungen mit einer Unterabfrage als Ziel</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Schlüsselwort WITH CHECK OPTION in DML-Anweisungen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Anweisung INSERT für mehrere Tabellen – Varianten</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Anweisung INSERT für mehrere Tabellen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Zeilen in einer Tabelle zusammenführen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Über einen Zeitraum erfolgte Datenänderungen überwachen</sub_topic>
    </sub_topics>
  </topic>
  <topic>Daten in verschiedenen Zeitzonen verwalten
    <sub_topics>
      <sub_topic>Zeitzonen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP und LOCALTIMESTAMP</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Datum und Uhrzeit in einer Sessionzeitzone vergleichen</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>DBTIMEZONE und SESSIONTIMEZONE</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>DATE und TIMESTAMP – Unterschiede</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>Datentypen INTERVAL</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>EXTRACT, TZ_OFFSET und FROM_TZ</sub_topic>
      <sub_topic>TO_TIMESTAMP, TO_YMINTERVAL und TO_DSINTERVAL</sub_topic>
    </sub_topics>
  </topic>
</topics>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_XINCLUDE);

print_r($xml);

?>

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [topic] => Array
  (
    [0] => Objekte mit Data Dictionary Views verwalten
    [1] => Größe Datensets bearbeiten
    [2] => Daten in verschiedenen Zeitzonen verwalten
  )
)
```

when I reduce the xml string to only use the  entry, simplexml_load_string discoveres the childnodes - but reduces the 'headline':

```
<?php

$str = '<topic>Objekte mit Data Dictionary Views verwalten
      <sub_topics>
        <sub_topic>Data Dictionary erläutern</sub_topic>
        <sub_topic>Dictionary Views</sub_topic>
        <sub_topic>Views USER_OBJECTS und ALL_OBJECTS</sub_topic>
        <sub_topic>Tabellen- und Spalteninformationen</sub_topic>
        <sub_topic>Dictionary Views nach Constraint-Informationen abfragen</sub_topic>
        <sub_topic>Dictionary Views nach View-, Sequence-, Index- und Synonyminformationen abfragen</sub_topic>
        <sub_topic>Tabellen Kommentare hinzufügen</sub_topic>
        <sub_topic>Dictionary Views nach Kommentarinformationen abfragen</sub_topic>
      </sub_topics>
    </topic>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
print_r($xml);
?>

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [sub_topics] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [sub_topic] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Data Dictionary erläutern
                    [1] => Dictionary Views
                    [2] => Views USER_OBJECTS und ALL_OBJECTS
                    [3] => Tabellen- und Spalteninformationen
                    [4] => Dictionary Views nach Constraint-Informationen abfragen
                    [5] => Dictionary Views nach View-, Sequence-, Index- und Synonyminformationen abfragen
                    [6] => Tabellen Kommentare hinzufügen
                    [7] => Dictionary Views nach Kommentarinformationen abfragen
                )

        )

)
```

.. Now I'm wondering if there is any other solution than crawling into
suspected areas by hand using xpath, use the array conversion for
those sub childs and merge the arrays afterwards.

This is one example of the full xml file I need to parse: http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/catalogs.xml_desc?p_id=D49988DE20&p_org_id=34&p_lang=D

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
To solve this issue, I used a different library that prints out arrays in a more complex way and is able to separate from child elements, attributes and node values: http://www.criticaldevelopment.net/xml/doc.php

Answer (score 0):

If you can access this data doing an AJAX request, I recommend you to use the jQuery.post() or jQuery.get() function, that can parse your XML just like json, and the other way.

It's javascript, but it's definitely the most simple way (as I know) to do treatment without spending hours on coding and searching, maybe not the solution that will suite best your needs, but it's a way you should look.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't fetch the xml using ajax because it is not allowed by the client because my app runs a different domain. To get around this, I'm making an ajax request to my server and fetch the xml using curl. Then I can process the data directly and do some more stuff with it (like converting it to an array and to json for further editing) - but that's where I'm stuck